# How to get current connection time?

Tags: networking, wifi, osx

Is there a way to get the current uptime for an interface?
I'd like to know for how long I'm connected in a wi-fi network unstop.

Comment: Not very easy to script, but there's probably a log entry from when the interface was activated. I have no idea where that log is on OSX.